# using ajax to reload php data from function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Attempting my first php program.  It pulls data from a mySQL database load the html.  I want to be able to change the data loaded based on a menu selection.  I'm not really certain what I need to do.  But this is what I've tried so far.

```
  <section id="UserComments" style="margin-left: 3em;">
    <?php load_comments($UsersID, $login_session, $ProjectID); echo "<br />" ?>
  </section>
```

PHP code (same page as above HTML)

```
function load_comments($UsersID,$username,$ProjectID) {  
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM UserComments JOIN Projects ON UserComments.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID WHERE UserID = '$UsersID' AND Projects.ProjectID = '$ProjectID'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<p class="note"><span></span>' . nl2br($row['UserComment']) . ' ';
        if ( empty($row['FileName']) ) {
            echo '<br><br><span id="rightfloat"><font color="#5bc0de">' . $username . '   at   ' . $row['DateSubmitted'] . '</font></span></p>';
        }else {
            $echo_file = '<a href="' . $row['UserFile'] . '"><img src="images/Attach-icon.png">' . $row['FileName'] . '  </a>';
            echo '<br><br><span id="rightfloat"><font color="#5bc0de">' . $echo_file . ' ' . $username . '   at   ' . $row['DateSubmitted'] . '</font></span><br></p>'; 
        }
    }  
    return;
}

function load_projects($UsersID) {
    global $connection;
    global $ProjectID;

    $sql = "SELECT Projects.ProjectID, Projects.ProjectName, Users.UserID FROM Projects JOIN CustomerProject ON CustomerProject.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID JOIN Users ON CustomerProject.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE CustomerProject.UserID = '$UsersID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $idname = "ProjID-" . $row['ProjectID'];
        echo '<a id="' . $idname . '" href="#" onclick="FindID(\'' . $idname . '\')">' . nl2br($row['ProjectName']) . '</a>';
    }   

    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function FindID(id_name) {
                var sel_name = document.getElementById(id_name);
                var sel_project_name = sel_name.textContent;

                $jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: \"comment-data.php\",
                    data: { 'proj_name': sel_project_name },
                    success: function(){ alert('success'); }, 
                    error: function(){ alert('failure'); }
                });
            }
        </script>
    ";
}
```

Ultimately, I'd like to use the success: section to reload my comment data based on the users menu selection (projects).  I really don't have any idea how to do that; but for now I've just been trying to see if there was a success or error.  That too is proving difficult for me at this time :/

Here is the comment-data.php:

```
require("DBConnection.php");
require_once("session.php");

$proj_name = $_POST['proj_name'];

$sql = "SELECT * Projects WHERE ProjectName = " . $proj_name;

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (!empty($result)){
     $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
     $ProjectID = $row['ProjectID'];

   // here was my feeble attempt to reload my comment data after the user selected a project from the db. This was not working, so I've commented out

   //  load_comments($UsersID, $login_session, $ProjectID);
} else {
    echo "Project not found in database!";
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? Do you get any error in browser console?

Comment: Nothing happens... It's as if there were no code there.  Doesn't change the existing comments that are there when first loading up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your project is good but there is something you need to know:

When your are making a class in php it is preferable that you gather them in a php class file that doesn't have any html so that when you need you just call them like that for example:

your.php

```
<?php
include ("class.php")
?>
<html>
//some html code for your website
 <section id="UserComments" style="margin-left: 3em;">
    <?php load_comments($UsersID, $login_session, $ProjectID); echo "<br />" ?>
  </section>
</html>
```

now you got this in place you can call you function at `comment-data.php`:

```
include ("class.php");
require("DBConnection.php");
require_once("session.php");

$proj_name = $_POST['proj_name'];

$sql = "SELECT * Projects WHERE ProjectName = " . $proj_name;

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (!empty($result)){
     $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
     $ProjectID = $row['ProjectID'];
     load_comments($UsersID, $login_session, $ProjectID);
     // it should work now
} else {
    echo "Project not found in database!";
}
```

Now for the ajax part, well i found out a way to get the html out and put it somewhere in the page but i am not sure , so here it is.

class.php

```
function load_comments($UsersID,$username,$ProjectID) {  
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM UserComments JOIN Projects ON UserComments.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID WHERE UserID = '$UsersID' AND Projects.ProjectID = '$ProjectID'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<p class="note"><span></span>' . nl2br($row['UserComment']) . ' ';
        if ( empty($row['FileName']) ) {
            echo '<br><br><span id="rightfloat"><font color="#5bc0de">' . $username . '   at   ' . $row['DateSubmitted'] . '</font></span></p>';
        }else {
            $echo_file = '<a href="' . $row['UserFile'] . '"><img src="images/Attach-icon.png">' . $row['FileName'] . '  </a>';
            echo '<br><br><span id="rightfloat"><font color="#5bc0de">' . $echo_file . ' ' . $username . '   at   ' . $row['DateSubmitted'] . '</font></span><br></p>'; 
        }
    }  
    return;
}

function load_projects($UsersID) {
    global $connection;
    global $ProjectID;

    $sql = "SELECT Projects.ProjectID, Projects.ProjectName, Users.UserID FROM Projects JOIN CustomerProject ON CustomerProject.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID JOIN Users ON CustomerProject.UserID = Users.UserID WHERE CustomerProject.UserID = '$UsersID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $idname = "ProjID-" . $row['ProjectID'];
        echo '<a id="' . $idname . '" href="#" onclick="FindID(\'' . $idname . '\')">' . nl2br($row['ProjectName']) . '</a>';
    }   

    echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            function FindID(id_name) {
                var sel_name = document.getElementById(id_name);
                var sel_project_name = sel_name.textContent;

                $jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: \"comment-data.php\",
                    data: 'proj_name='+ sel_project_name,
                    success : function(code_html, status){
                      $(code_html).appendTo("#somewhereinthehtml");
                      alert('success');
                    }, 
                    error: function(){ alert('failure'); }
                });
            }
        </script>
    ";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help; but same problem.  The "UserComments" section isn't getting changed when selecting a project from the menu.  First time loading, it loads everything as expected - based on the default project (the first one).  But when going to the menu to choose a different one; nothing happens.  Maybe I'm not declaring the Ajax or jQuery correctly ?

Comment: Finally, after fighting with it all day and all night, I managed to get it going!  I've changed so many little things here and there, so I don't know what change actually made it work.  But this definitely put me on the right track! Without your help; I'd still  be hopelessly lost!